# Flutter Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._version on web

Tags: ajax, flutter, web, request

I use packages
http: ^ 0.12.2

this is my iport

```
import 'package: http / http.dart' as http;
import 'dart: io';
import 'dart: convert';
```

for retrieving the data from a server. It works fine with Android and iOS. But on the web I get the error message Unsupported operation: Platform._version

this is my function:

```
Future getUserData() async {
    var url_ = "${APIDomain}/antragsteller/1";
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

      HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url_));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      request.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

      String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      this.userData = jsonDecode(reply);
  }
```

the return value is then of course empty. My internet search did not produce any useful results.
Can someone please help me find the cause and solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: can you solve this?

Comment: ubgraded package to http: ^0.13.3, refactored the cal to  final http.Response response = await client.get(Uri.parse(_url),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      );

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an issue on Dart SDK libraries and Flutter for web as documented on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39998). This has been resolved for the [http](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/149) plugin, updating to the latest version of the plugin should solve the issue.

Comment: I've installed the last plugin and the issie persksts